# Is it possible to study Measure Theory from the definition of Measure?

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

I would like to start studying Measure Theory in the summer of 2024. Let me tell you a bit about myself:

**I'm a graduate student in Mathematics from Brazil. I suspect that, by luck, I ended up being approved for a Master's in Mathematics at an excellent graduate program. My university (where I'm graduating) is far from being one of the best and I don't have a good grounding in mathematical analysis. I've recently dedicated myself a lot to studying real analysis, as you can see in some of my recent posts, and I managed to get approved for the master's degree (they're different universities).**

Looking at the class notes from last summer at the university where I'll be doing my master's, I had a hard time understanding some of the results. For example:

**Theorem 1.** Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{X})$. Then the functions defined by: $f(x) = \text{inf}_{n} \ f_n(x)$,  $F(x) = \text{sup}_{n} \ f_n(x)$,  $f^*(x) = \text{sup}_{n \geq 1} \{ \text{inf}_{m \geq n} \ f_m(x)\}$ and $F^*(x) = \text{inf}_{n \geq 1} \{ \text{sup}_{m \geq n} \ f_m(x)\}$ are measurable functions.

**Theorem 2.** If $f,g \in \mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{X}),$ then $fg \in \mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{X})$.

**Lema 3.** If $f \in \mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{X})$ is non-negative then there exists a sequence $(\phi_n)_n$ in $\mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{X})$ such that:

1. $0 \leq \phi_n(x) \leq \phi_{n + 1}(x)$, for all $x \in X$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \longrightarrow \infty} \phi_n(x)$, for all $x \in X$.
3. Every $\phi_n(x)$ takes on a finite number of real values.

So my question is: **Can I start the study of Measure Theory from the definition of Measure without getting too bogged down?**

I have a reasonable understanding of what a sigma-algebra is, what a measure space is and, from the definition of measure, the subject seems more understandable to me. I also plan to ask the teacher about these three theorems next year.

Comment: I think there is no other starting point - if you want to talk about measurable functions, you need to know what measure is.

Comment: Actually, you do not need a measure to define a measurable function. But you are right that a some point you would like/need to deal with measures to do cool stuff.